# Windows 10 How to install language pack offline?

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

At work I have a  Windows-10 computer and the IT department helpfully  blocked all Microsoft sites: thanks Microsoft for so frequent updates that they ate up all our  traffic limit,  so the IT decided to cut it off completely. How can I install a language pack by downloading it at home or in an Internet cafe?

---

Note: please don't be confused by the mention of the IT department: requesting them to unblock the sites is absolutely not an option. So, for whatever reason that Windows-10 computer has no connection, and will never have it; How can I install a language pack on it?.

Comment: IIRC MS hasn't provided offline installers for language packs for a few years now. Corporate licensing usually allows things like this. As systems need to be kept up to date simply for security reasons, I'd assume the IT staff does it using local resources. I'd also assume that there's a business reason for you to have a language pack. Isn't it then really the IT dept's responsibility to arrange it? If they refuse I'd talk to my mgr.

Comment: Note that from other questions OP has posed, they claim this is a personally owned device they use for work purposes, that is only somewhat controlled by their IT department, with that control possibly only extending to the internet connection.

Comment: If, as you say elsewhere, the IT depts control only extends to the internet connection and you have otherwise full control of the computer, you could install a VPN solution to get around whatever filtering your IT dept is running and therefore download and install anything you please. If, however, ITs control extends to the computer itself, this will not be a viable solution, and you may need to clarify things.